# Safely Ignore JSON Property that Contains All Other Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I am working with Spring Boot, and am parsing a JSON file with Jackson. The file looks like this

```
{
    "grouping": [
        {
            "obj1": "value1",
            "obj2": "value2",
            "obj3": "value3",
            "obj4": "value4"
        },
        {
            "obj1": "value1",
            "obj2": "value2",
            "obj3": "value3",
            "obj4": "value4"
            },
        },
        {
            "obj1": "value1",
            "obj2": "value2",
            "obj3": "value3",
            "obj4": "value4"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

When I parse it with Jackson's ObjectMapper it throws an error saying I haven't defined "grouping" using @JsonProperty. The problem is I don't care about this initial heading, but if I ignore it (using @JsonIgnoreProperties("grouping"), then the rest of the data is skipped and I currently end up with one object with defaault constructor values in it.

Do I need to create a throw away variable or do I need to restructure my objects/classes?

Comment: Well, you have an object with a grouping array... Just parse a JSON array... Don't make an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities:

1) create variable `grouping` and parse result as object:
For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Holder holder = mapper.readValue(content, Holder.class);
ObjHolder[] objHolder = holder.getGrouping().getObjHolderArray();
```

2) read whole JSON as JsonNode, navigate to `grouping` and parse it's content to array. For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(content);
JsonNode array = actualObj.get("grouping");
ObjHolder[] objHolders = mapper.treeToValue(array, ObjHolder[].class);
```

Comment: This was correct, specifically needed to:
`JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree("file_name"));

String arrayString = jsonNode.get("grouping").toString();

MyArraylist= objectMapper.readValue(arrayString, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){});`